# Uploading to Amazon S3 using Pre-Built Credentials

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a `File` to AWS where I already have most the info that the SDK would generate stored in a `Map<String, String>` (they were provided by an API):

```
"Content-Type": "application/pdf",
"bucket": "bucket-name",
"acl": "private",
"key": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"policy": "xxxxxxxx==",
"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
"x-amz-credential": "ASIAxxxxxxxxx/20180202/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request",
"x-amz-signature": "xxxx"
"x-amz-date": "yyyyMMddThhmmssZ",
"x-amz-meta-a": "some meta data",
"x-amz-meta-b": "some meta data"
```

So far I have:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType(map.get("Content-Type"));
metadata.setSSEAlgorithm(map.get("x-amz-algorithm"));

Map<String, String> userMetadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
userMetadata.put("a", map.get("x-amz-meta-a"));
metadata.setUserMetadata(userMetadata);

s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
    map.get("bucket"),
    map.get("ket"),
    new FileInputStream(file),
    metadata
))
```

How do I now set the `credential` and `signature` fields?

If it makes more sense **not** to use the SDK for this then some examples would be much appreciated, I've not managed to get it working yet with a simple HTTP `post`.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html ? ;)

Comment: @maio290 Yes, they all seem to require at least the access key ID and secret key ID. I don't have either but I do have the `credential` and `signature` already built which is what the SDK generates itself.

Comment: From digging into the documentation (I really never worked with S3 tbh), there is actually one example with the headers you got:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Since the SDK seems to be fully focused on the accessKey and secret, you may try to avoid it and simply send a PUT request by hand like they did with the GET request in the link I found. This may work, but that's as far as I got from only reading the documentation, so good luck :)

Comment: @maio290 Thanks for digging, looks like I'll have to admit defeat and use a HTTP `post`/`put` directly then :(

Comment: That's not that bad. Actually, the API you're calling is making it pretty easy for you (from my understanding) - as stated in the documentation, this is "A use case scenario for presigned URLs is that you can grant temporary access to your Amazon S3 resources. " - so you just have to put their given headers on your request. Doesn't sound like a reason to be sad :)